# Spec of some rings: drawing pictures

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

In the book Commutative Algebra by Atiyah-McDonald, the authors ask a question:

> Draw pictures of Spec($\mathbb{Z}$), Spec($\mathbb{R}$),Spec($\mathbb{C}[x]$),Spec($\mathbb{R}[x]$),Spec($\mathbb{Z}[x]$).

Here I know the structure of prime ideals in each of these rings; but I could not get, what it is meant to draw pictures of these spectrums. Can one help for it?

---

(I just saw an analogous question after posting mine - [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156329/how-to-draw-pictures-of-prime-spectra?rq=1); it has two comments around 10 years old, and I could not see answer to my question through links there. The answer to old question is commenting why pictures are useful; here, I am asking, "what should I understand to draw pictures of Spec(R) for various rings R"?

Comment: Mumford's red book contains a picture for $\mathbb Z[x]$, so maybe you can try drawing a similar picture for the other rings.

Comment: Do you by any chance mean by McDonald the mathematician [Macdonald](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_G._Macdonald)?